# How to build a gmail chat-bot?

Tags: gmail, bots

I have read similar questions but they talk of AI models. What I want to do is build a simple bot which accepts predefined commands and performs required action. No learning needed. I have the whole flowchart prepared. What I need is to get the commands that a user types in his/her chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conference bot](http://coders.meta.net.nz/~perry/jabber/confbot.php) could be able to do for that purpose, which is written in python.

Comment: I tried running the code and I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\Desktop\confbot\bot\confbot.py", line 1121, in <module>
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\traceback.py", line 227, in print_exc
    print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit, file)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\traceback.py", line 129, in print_exception
    _print(file, lines[-1], '')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: Which version of Confbot is it, @Jack?

Comment: @Jack, looks like connection failed according to your traceback, you know that bot will need an google account, and could you double check you have put the account and password when it first ask for? you can change those in confbot.ini later on.

Comment: @you

Anyway to build chatbot using PHP ? any layman tutorial ?