# Gmail Chat in PHP

Tags: php, gmail, bots

I'm wondering how the best way to build a way to interface with Gmail Chat is. I haven't found anything that looks incredibly easy to do yet. One thought it to build it all from scratch, the other thought would be to grab the code from open source software. What are your thoughts on how to proceed and what would be the best way? I'm not necessarily looking for the fastest way as this is a bit of a learning project for me.same as found on stack overflow [How to build a gmail chat-bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558181/how-to-build-a-gmail-chat-bot)

Answer (score 0):

GMail chat/ Google Talk uses the XMPP protocol for communication. [Here's one example of a PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) that allows you to connect to XMPP networks. [Here's a list at xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Comment: This is the very good for me but it doesn't give any method to read the chat.Is there is any other api for reading the gmail chat.As I found on google but didn't find anything related to it in php.This api will just only allow me to post the chat.Thanks for the help.

Comment: The example on `xmpphp`'s homepage shows an example of receiving messages and status updates.